# MacVim : How do I delete all the misspelled words highlighted in MacVim?

Tags: vim, macvim

I am very new to MacVim & I want to know if I can delete all the misspelled words highlighted with a command? I have thousands of lines in my txt and I really need to delete all the misspelled words. They are in En_US.

Thanks in advance.

Best regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do that with a macro:

```
qq]sde

qq     " start recording a macro in the register q
]s     " go to the next misspelled word
dw     " delete the word
```

Then you can delete the next 100 misspelled word with `100@q`.

Depending on your configuration/need, you may want to delete the next WORD with `dW` or search for the next bad word with `]S`.

Have a look at http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/spell.html